# MSMQ FIFO/Synchronous Processing

Tags: vb.net, msmq

I have a one threaded application.  Its supposed to connect to a local MSMQ queue, and once a message is received it should process it before continuing to listen for additional messages.  The messages contain data that is supposed to be inserted into a database table. But before inserting the data, it does a query to see if the item already exists.  However, I am thinking that by creating a handler for ReceiveCompleted, that if more than one messages is in the queue that multiple threads are being spawned off. Is that what will happen? If it is then its possible that duplicate data could be in both messages, and my sql query may not see any duplication because the 2nd thread is still working and has not yet inserted its data into the database table.

```
Dim objQueue As New MessageQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("myQueuePath"))
AddHandler objQueue.ReceiveCompleted, AddressOf QueueReceived
objQueue.BeginReceive()

Private Sub QueueReceived(source As Object, asyncResult As ReceiveCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim mq = DirectCast(source, MessageQueue)
    Dim objMessage As Message = Nothing
    Try
        mq.Formatter = New XmlMessageFormatter(New [String]() {"System.String,mscorlib"})
        objMessage = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult)
        Dim strMessage As String = objMessage.Body.ToString()
        
        'Call routine to read data, check for suplicates and then insert into database 
        ProcessBXRS(objMessage)
    Catch ex As Exception
         'Do some exception handling
    End Try

    'Listen for next message
    mq.BeginReceive()
End Sub
```

Comment: No.  You have to call BeginReceive() again to get the event to fire for the next message.  You always put that at the end of the event handler to ensure there's no overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to call BeginReceive() again.